# C - Display function prints nothing out; Trouble using a parameter for display function

Tags: c

I had to write a deck of cards generating program today, but I am not sure why the console window turns up nothing when I run it. The aim is to have it print all the cards from the struct array as such: "...[42 4-C] [ 8 9-H] [43 5-S] [33 8-D] [34 9-C] [21 9-D]...". The last build error I had before I got rid of it was when I tried to use LoadDeck() in the parameter of DealCards(), and it said singlecard was not compatible with singlecard*. I got rid of the error by making a new struct singlecard array, and using memcpy with LoadDeck() which returns a singlecard array. Need a bit of help.

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
struct singlecard LoadDeck();
bool CheckDup(int trialNum, struct singlecard deck[]);
char LoadFace(int cardnum);
char LoadSuit(int cardnum);
DealCards(struct singlecard deck[]);
struct singlecard
{
    int cardnum;
    char face;
    char suit;
};
int main()
{
    struct singlecard aNewDeck[52];
    memcpy(aNewDeck, LoadDeck(), 52);
    DealCards(aNewDeck);
}
struct singlecard LoadDeck()
{
    struct singlecard deck[52];
    srand(time(NULL));
    int i=0;
    int r = 1 + rand() % 52;

    while (i < 52)
    {
        if (CheckDup(r, deck) == false)
        {
            deck[i].cardnum = r;
            deck[i].face = LoadFace(r);
            deck[i].suit = LoadSuit(r);
            i++;
        }
    }

    return deck[52];
}
bool CheckDup(int trialNum, struct singlecard deck[])
{
    bool duplicate = false;
    int i = 0;
    while (i < 52 || duplicate == false)
    {
        if (trialNum = deck[i].cardnum)
        {
            duplicate = true;
        }
        else
        {
            i++;
        }
    }
    return duplicate;
}
char LoadFace(int cardnum)
{
    char faces[] = { 'A','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','T','J','Q','K' };
    int factor = cardnum % 14;
    return faces[factor];
}
char LoadSuit(int cardnum)
{
    char suits[] = { 'H','D','C','S' };
    int factor = cardnum % 5;
    return suits[factor];
}
DealCards(struct singlecard deck[])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 52; i++)
    {
        printf("[%d %c-%c]", deck[i].cardnum, deck[i].face, deck[i].suit);
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you do any debugging at all?

Comment: `char suits[] = { 'H','D','C','S' };
    int factor = cardnum % 5; return suits[factor];` --> review the use of `5`.

Comment: @FurkanKambay For this specific issue, not too much, because I am not sure where the issue may lie. I tried checking if making srand(time(null)) to srand(1) would give me results but that didn't.

Comment: If `memcpy(aNewDeck, LoadDeck(), 52);` doesn't flag a fat compiler warning, your warnings are nowhere *near* high enough. And fyi, `LoadDeck` invokes *undefined behavior* by accessing the declared array out of range. That function should have the deck to initialize passed by argument, or wrapped in its own structure. Also, `LoadFace` should use `% 13`, not `% 14`. There are only 13 faces in standard deck (and in you array). Zero-based array indexing. Pretty important when learning C.

Comment: @Paul if you knew where the issue is, the debugger isn't necessary. Conversely, that is why you need it. When debugging, comment out `srand` so the results are repeatable.

Comment: First do what chux said. That 5 needs to be 4. Then do some debugging. It may be something obvious.

Comment: @FurkanKambay

Update: I tried to make a premade struct singlecard array and this is the result (and I could not run it without making the array size 4 or else I would get a warning/s saying "buffer 'aNewDeck' of size 24 bytes will be overrun; 1 bytes will be written starting at offset 24"

https://i.gyazo.com/8df23281baca006c58ca814fadfcd391.png

Comment: @Paul first off, did you do what the other comments said about the mod operator? The 5 in `LoadSuit` needs to be 4 and the 14 above needs to be 13. And about what you just said, since you are setting the value on index 3, the array needs to be of size 4 since index numbers start at 0. So that buffer error was normal.

Comment: Once you correct those, try the same thing again with the hard-coded values. And please copy the console output instead of posting a link to a screen shot of it.

Comment: @FurkanKambay   Still messing around to fix it, but wanted to mention that I did correct those things already when I pasted that screenshot.

Comment: In the image, you assign `cardnum`s of 0,1,2 but the others are for 1,2,3 so some of them look corrupt. Do it all for 0,1,2 so the length is 3 and see if the output looks good.

Comment: @FurkanKambay WOOPS forgot to change those after changing the first indexes lol.

    [5 Q-S][3 6-H][24 A-D][-858993460 ╠-╠][-858993460 ╠-╠]    [-858993460 ╠-╠][-85899346
0 ╠-╠][-858993460 ╠-╠] 

It works now (With the hardcoded array), but I still get these additional outputs.

I also made the dealcards forloop use "i < sizeof(deck);" instead of 52.

Comment: Can you try printing `sizeof(deck)` to the console?

Answer (score 0):

I would add to comments, but have not the points so "answer" is the way ...

In addition to the %13 and %4 and zero-based-indexing and random number generation there are other issues that need to be addressed:

- You specify the function LoadDeck returns a single structure, but you code that it returns an array
- The memcpy uses name of a function as an argument, a function that is stated to return a single structure which should trigger a SEGV (I think), but instead gets an array of structures so may fool the runtime system
- The memcpy of LoadDeck uses "52" as a "bytes to copy" argument but instead should specify "52 * sizeof(struct)" to copy
- You specified in LoadDeck that the array is declared in the function but returns that array into a single-structure slot.  This is incorrect because you cannot return a local-to-function variable since it goes out of scope at function exit and that memory location can be compromised by other operations.  This is also incorrect because a "single slot" is not the same in the call-stack as a full array.